# mysql / php fetch results from query and return table name where results where found?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a MySQL query to see if there are any recent changes made to two of my tables. This works by checking the database to see if there are any records held with a date less than 30 days old.

I am searching 2 tables in my query, 'supplier_invoices' and 'supplier_bank_details' and if either table contains records that are within 30 days old then it should show these results.

However I am struggling to do the next bit,

I want to be able to tell which table it found the result in so that it can echo out the right line, either 'you changed your bank details' or 'you submitted an invoice'.

for instance if a user changes there bank details then it should echo:

```
'Bank details changed     {sortcode}      {account number}    about 2 days ago'
```

and/or if a supplier submits an invoice it should show/also show:

```
'invoice submited      {reference}      {status}    about 2 days ago'
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>

<?php
$tbl_name3 = 'supplier_bank_details';
$tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices';
$query3 = "select * from $tbl_name2 as $tbl_name2_result, $tbl_name3 as $tbl_name3_result WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die( mysql_error() );
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3); 


$datetime1 = new DateTime(); // Today's Date/Time
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row3['date']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


$account_number = '****'.substr($row3['account_number'], -4);

if(mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

if(mysql_num_rows($tbl_name2_result) > 0) {

echo '<div class="contracts_area"><div class="table_header"></div>';
echo '<div class="request"><p>Bank Details Changed</p><p>'.$row3['sort_code'].'</p><p>'.$account_number.'</p><p>about '.$interval->format('%d days ago').'</p></div>';
echo '</div>';

}else{

if(mysql_num_rows($tbl_name3_result) > 0) {

echo '<div class="contracts_area"><div class="table_header"></div>';
echo '<div class="request"><p>Invoice Raised</p></div>';
echo '</div>';
}   
}

echo '<div class="no_activity">No Recent Activity</div>';    

} ?>
```

Comment: ew, `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated as per the PHP Manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function as you already have the field names in the result so just get the name of the table to which the field belongs by

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php

An example from the same link

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT account.*, country.* FROM account, country WHERE country.name = 'Portugal' AND account.country_id = country.id";

// get the result from the DB
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Lists the table name and then the field name
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
    $table = mysql_field_table($result, $i);
    $field = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

    echo  "$table: $field\n";
}

?>
```

Please use mysqli_ functions as mysql_ is deprecated and will not be supported by the future versions

Comment: thanks for this however this only gives me the column names as opposed to the values stored in that column. how would I amend this to give me the values as opposed to the column name?

Comment: @JamesDaley mysql_field_table returns the table name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of the tables have a unique column name you can identify them by, why not just check for NULL values in these columns.

Eg.

```
  <?php
        $tbl_name3 = 'supplier_bank_details';
        $tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices';
        $query3 = "select * from $tbl_name2 as $tbl_name2_result, $tbl_name3 as $tbl_name3_result WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die( mysql_error() );
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){

            // your unique column for Bank Details
            if( !is_null($row3['sortcode']) ) {

                echo 'your code for when Bank details are found';

            }
            // your unique column for Invoice Details
            if( !is_null($row3['reference'])) { 

                echo 'your code for when Invoice details are found';
            }

        }
        ?>
```

If the value isn't null for the said column, you should have results from the table in which contains the respective column name.

Comment: thanks I tried this but for some reason even though my supplier_bank_details table only has one result in it is echoing out 'your code for when bank details are found' about 5 times despite there only being one result? its doing exactly the same but for the invoices table. any ideas?

Comment: `var_dump()` the data and post it here (add it to your question) so I can see what you're working with. Alternatively, post the query results from the mysql command-line client... I really need to see what data you're working with.